# Building old android project in Android Studio, getting kotlin errors

Tags: java, android, kotlin

It's been a while since I built my android application. (new hard drive now, fresh install of the latest android studio)

When I build, I get Kotlin related errors.  I am not using Kotlin. Any ideas?
Help much appreciated!
cheers,

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar
Required by:
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.0
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.1.0
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.0
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.0
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.0
    project :BaseGameUtils > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.0
```

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle files, at least their `buildscript`, `repositories` and `dependencies` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jcenter()` to the list of Gradle repos. The Kotlin dependencies aren't present in the Google maven repo.

There should be an `allprojects` block in the root `build.gradle` file where you add the repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        //Other repos...
        jcenter()
        //Other repos...
    }
}
```